# What is the GID/UID of the system on Android?

Tags: android, c, linux, uid

How do I identify the number (integer value) of a particular group associated with a file?

```
ls -l
drwxr-x--x root     system              2014-11-26 10:59 xyz
```

I have managed to check that `group id of root is 0`. What is the corresponding **number of group id** for **system**?

I need to change the group of my file to system. How do I do it using [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)? gid_t is internally of int type. So what value should I pass to make it system? How do I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with AID_XXX Ex: `AID_SYSTEM` in the source code. The corresponding value is the integer value of it.

```
AID_SYSTEM is 1000
```

Similarly it can be found for other groups as well.

I don't know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

At adb shell

```
su 1000
```

since 1000 is the system uid

```
id
```

This returns

```
uid=1000(system) gid=1000(system)
```

So gid for system is 1000 too

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about files specifically, the easiest way is just `ls -n`:

```
$ ls -ld /data
drwxrwx--x system   system            2015-06-04 11:59 data
$ ls -ldn /data
drwxrwx--x 1000     1000              2015-06-04 11:59 data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chgrp 1000 /path/filename
```

1000 is the system group id, and also the system user id

`chgrp` is included in `busybox`.